# Issue with Tikz Intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, ipad

I am getting the error:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size = 120].

Full MWE::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h] \label{diagram}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (A1)        at (-1, -1);
    \coordinate (A2)        at ( 1, 1) ;
    \coordinate (Acon)      at (0.5,0) ;
    \coordinate (B1)        at (1, -1) ;
    \coordinate (B2)        at (-1, 1) ;
    \coordinate (Bcon)      at (0, 0.5);

    \draw[name path = lineA] (A1)..controls(Acon)..(A2) node[above]{$A$};
    \draw[name path = lineB] (B1) -- (B2) node[above]{$B$};

    \fill[black, name intersections = {of = lineA and lineB}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node[above right]{$f(p)$};

    \end{tikzpicture} \caption{$\phi(A)$ and $\phi(B)$ in $\mathbb{C}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I change `lineA` to be

```
\draw[name path = lineA] (A1) -- (A2) node[above]{$A$};
```

everything works.

FYI: I’m using TeXPad on iPad.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Nonetheless I would guess this is because TeX/TikZ doesn't know what `(Acon)` is?

Comment: @StefanPinnow sadly thats not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. For me this works perfectly fine using TikZ v3.0.1a both, using PDFLaTeX and using LuaLaTeX ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for testing, I guess I’ll just have to run it on my computer. :/

Comment: Depending on the version of and way you're using TeXPad, this may be off-topic (and why it fails) because it may not really be TeX. Or it may be that the version of and way you're using it does get you TeX, but an outdated version. Or maybe the limits are set differently and it is as simple as that.

Comment: Any news here? Have you tested this on your computer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is most likely that the question is solved by updating PGFPlots to the most recent version (v1.16).